# PHP: Having trouble uploading large files

Tags: php, webforms, file-upload

I am doing a file upload using PHP, which works fine for a file of size 2.8MB on my localhost - but not my Mediatemple GS host. Files smaller than 2MB work fine, but anything larger seems to not work... I am not getting any error message but when the upload finishes, the file is not found in the uploads directory...

I googled around, and I added the following lines to the .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 120M
php_value max_execution_time 120
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
```

I know some of the above values are a overkill, but even then, this does not seem to help... Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Your webhost may not allow those php_value's to be overwritten by htaccess. I would check with them.

And a bit overkill is an understatement, this may also have an effect. I would set them to realistic values. IE: post_max_size 120M given that your memory limit is 120M.

Comment: Do apache configs even support G? See premiso's comment about realistic values.  Try expressing it in megabytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one you missed is [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time), and do check whether your edits are reflected in `phpinfo();`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the phpinfo() and look for these four values - it's possible that the changes you think you're making haven't been applied, or that something else is overriding your changes.  The values you've changed look correct to me.