# Trouble uploading files in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload files using php, and it works perfectly up until 1Mb, I already [checked the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325917/php-having-trouble-uploading-large-files) and saw that the common thing missing was to edit this values on php.ini (I am using WAMP):

> post_max_size = 8G upload_max_filesize
>   = 2G

as you can see I already changed them up to Gigabytes and still it isn't working, what happens is that I click on upload and it goes to my upload.php file and just hangs in there writing nothing into the DB.

I had this in my HTML but I commented it already:

```
<!--input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000000" /-->
```

my upload php is:

```
<?php
include("mysql.class.php");
$mysql = new MySQL();
$tbl_name="documento";
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
    $myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (name, size, type, archivo,user_username ) ".
    "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content','$myusername')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 


    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
    header("location:admin.php");
} 
?>
```

What am I missing here? Also, when I upload images (since 180kbs) and I download them to check they uploaded correctly I am not able to see the image however documents have no problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to add slashes to the content of files?

Comment: that's just how I was taught to do that, is it not correct?

Comment: Also, why are you storing the contents in the database?

Comment: because they will later be used by other users, I assume you mean instead of just uploading them via FTP?

Comment: @Luis See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401761/remote-image-file-to-sqlite-blob-in-php/3401861#3401861

Comment: hahaha I didn't know that, ok, so I'll see about doing that

Comment: @NullUserException He's adding slashes because he's trying to stop SQL injection attacks. Correct thing to do, except you should use  http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php not addslashes. But it is better to store attached files in the file system.

Comment: By the way, it's not a good idea to give PHP 8 GB of data. Is FTP not an option?

Comment: I just placed 8Gb because I thought that was the problem, but now it seems I have basically all wrong =/ so I'll redo it with everything you guys have told me here

Comment: Never do such things like setting a limit on 8GB. I don't think your server has that much memory. Before changing such a setting, do some research: what happens when I alter this value? Debian made a famous [mistake with SSL](http://practical-tech.com/operating-system/linux/open-source-security-idiots/) in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

You're escaping the contents of the file. That will mostly be the cause that image doesn't get displayed. **Escaping should take place when you're about to send data to remote targets** (use `htmlentities()` for sending 'text' to the browser, use `mysql_real_escape_string` for sending data to the MySQL database). You should take a look in the [PHP manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), how to correctly implement file uploading.

When uploading a file to PHP, follow these rules:

1. Check whether a file is uploaded or not: `isset($_FILES['userfile'])`
2. Check whether the file upload was successful (`$_FILES['userfile']['error'] === 0`). If not, display a corresponding error message. See [this page for possible errors](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).
3. Check the file size (maximum size): `$_FILES['userfile']['size'] < 102400` (limits the file size to 100 kB)
   (optionally check whether the file is empty or not, this depends on your application)
4. If you're going to use the file name, sanitize it, by stripping out forbidden characters: `$sanitizedFileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_-]#i', '', $_FILES['userfile']['name']);`
5. Check the extension on the sanitized name, whether it's allowed or not:

   ```
   $allowedExtensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'txt', 'gif');
   $dotPos = strrchr($_FILES['userfile']['name'], '.');
   $ext = '';
   // Both FALSE and 0 will not match, I consider 'htaccess' in '.htaccess' not as an extension
   if($dotPos){
      // we are not interested whether the extension is in uppercase or lowercase
      $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $dotPos));
   }
   if(!in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)){
      echo 'Extension not allowed';
   }
   else{
      // continue with uploading
   }
   ```
6. Optionally, use image functions to verify an image, and limit the dimension (width x height) with [getimagesize()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).
7. Use [`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile'], "$targetDir/$sanitizedFileName")`](http://php.net/move-uploaded-file) or store the contents (`file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])`) in the database.
   When storing in the database, do not forget to [escape](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) your data.

Comment: He's adding slashes because he's trying to stop SQL injection attacks. People with good intentions who have never heard of http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php do this. No need to swear. Just correct them politely (but quite urgently).

Comment: I've already noticed that it was an attempt to escape data for the database. But that's not the right way to do it. I've now put more emphasis on the escaping part.

Comment: I liked it better when it started with "What the hell are you doing"

Comment: You can always see revision history for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it has something to do with your `addslashes($content)` statement. As lekensteyn said, this could cause binary data (such as in an image) to be corrupted. Instead of using `addslashes()`, take a look at PHP's [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.

Additionally, I don't think its considered best practice, in most cases, to store data such as file uploads in a database. You should consider saving the file on the disk and just store its filename in the database. Storing files up to 2GB in your database would create a needless burden for your MySQL server.